# special character in snippet Shortcut

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-snippets

I am using VS2010, i want to create a snippet to do the following:

When I press `{` or `(` then press tab the snippet writes `)` or `}`. I created the snippets but when I write `{` or `(` which are specified as the snippets shortcuts they does not work

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't use these characters for the snippet shortcut, refer to this MSDN article: [Code Snippets (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The yellow note at the end of the article says the following:

> For C# code snippets, **the characters that are valid for specifying the  field are**: alphanumeric characters, the number sign (#), the tilde character (~), the underscore character (_), and the en dash character (-).

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer a little left field here.

With the braces `{}` the reason that C# doesn't have a snippet is for formatting.  You'll notice as you write the code, when you type the `}` character, the editor will set your tabs correctly for the code you've just typed.  For this reason, it should be the last thing you write in your code.

Secondly, you'll notice to use a snippet, you have to type:

1. Snippet Name
2. Tab to Argument
3. Type Argument
4. Hit Enter.

For a 1 character snippet that results in one character, you've just swapped 2 keystrokes for at least three (`{` `tab` `enter`).  Ergo the C# team probably didn't think supporting this as a snippet was a good idea.

Comment: i don't think so sure cuz i read once "if you open a bracket you have to close it first then write your code inside" imagine you have condition like if(((variable)?((int)var2):var3) != 3) or something like that if you don't close the bracket immediately after you open it you will be confusing

Comment: First, that still includes you swap 2 keystrokes for 3; second, that's why the editor highlights the opening bracket when your cursor is near the corresponding closing bracket and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

These features are supported by "Productivity Power Tools" how you can live without these extensions in VS 2010.

Get all the goodies from here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/

Comment: Welcome to SO, Musab Ahmed Ali. I've removed the greetings from your answer, since it's just noise. If you have any questions, please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) or visit [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).